# MVC MultiSelectList posts NULL when form is submitted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, http-post

I'm having difficulty capturing posted values from a MultiSelectList.  When the page loads, the select list controls get successfully populated from Lists in my model. But when the form is submitted, the model lists are null.

These properties are in my "Contact" model.  The Contact object simply has an ExternalUserID (int) and a PublicName (string) property.

```
    public List<Contact> AvailableContacts { get; set; }

    public List<Contact> SelectedContacts { get; set; }
```

These controls are on my form.

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.AvailableContacts,
    new MultiSelectList(Model.AvailableContacts, "ExternalUserID", "PublicName", null),
    new { @class = "form-control", size = "15" })

@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedContacts,
    new MultiSelectList(Model.SelectedContacts, "ExternalUserID", "PublicName", null),
    new { @class = "form-control", size = "15" })
```

And this is my controller.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult EditContacts(Contacts model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Code to save omitted for clarity.
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

This probably requires some simple tweak, and may have been asked before, but I've not found a solution on SO or a concise example online.  If you're inclined to flag this as a duplicate, then please include a link to a concise example.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Whats the difference between `Contact` and `Contacts`? You have a List of `Contact`, but the model expected in the method is a `Contact`? MAybe the method should expect a `Contact`?

Comment: Did you check with fiddler or a similar what is actually sent over the channel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a property to bind the selected items to. A multiple `<Select>` binds to, and post back an array of value types.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public int[] SelectedContacts { get; set; }
  public List<Contact> AvailableContacts { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedContacts, new SelectList(Model.AvailableContacts, "ExternalUserID", "PublicName"), new { @class = "form-control", size = "15" })
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen. That was it, plus I needed to select the options in that list on submit, like so:  $('form').on('submit', function () { $('#SelectedContacts option').prop('selected', 'selected'); });  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean _"I needed to select the options on submit"_? That piece of jquery is absolutely not required and suggests you have other problems as well. Or your not understanding what a ListBox is - you need 1 only ListBox that displays all `AvailableContacts` and bind it to a `int[] SelectedContacts`. If you have values for `ExternalUserID` of say 1 to 10, and you set `SelectedContacts` to say [ 2, 4 ] in the controller then the 2nd and 4th options will be selected. If in the view you select the 1st and 5th options, the value of `SelectedContacts` will be [ 1, 5 ] on post back

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify.  The context on this is that I have a pair of list boxes, one on the left and one on the right. There are arrow controls between those boxes, and users can move list items from one list to the other. It's similar to something like this (http://www.vb123.com/PublishingImages/200405_rr1.jpg), but on a web interface. Because of this format, no item on the right listbox was selected at the time of submission, because the user clicks arrow controls to move the items into a list. The items were just sitting in that listbox unselected. That's why I needed the script.

Comment: You're right, using a listbox in the traditional, standard way, that script would be unnecessary.  Thanks for pointing that out.